# Branching in Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

We need to create a new project in Visual Source safe. This project is actually a newer version of an existing project. Following is what we want.

1. All files of existing project are copied to new project.
2. Files in both projects are not shared. (Changing a file in one project should not affect the same file in other project)
3. All Visual Studio solutions and projects are bound to new project in source safe.

Whats is the best and easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the share and branch option...

[MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dw155ey%28VS.80%29.aspx) (works with folders as well as files)

This will break the link between the two copies meaning that you can change files in one project without affecting the other one.

Comment: As others may point out, the best solution is to not use VSS in the first place.

Comment: what about source control bindings of my visual studio projects?

Comment: Set up a new working folder for the new project and get the files. The bindings will be set up to the new location.

Comment: That didn't work. I had to open visual studio solutions and change the source control bindings one by one.

Comment: Even if you choose to open the project within Visual Studio directly from SourceSafe? I thought this fixed up the bindings automatically.

Comment: @AntonyW: agree, as well as do not use bindings at all (they make unnoticed changes to source files) - use manual checkout-checkin